# Using a Data Frame Column as start & another as end for range to calculate mean for another dataframe column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have 2 dataframes, 1 that contains start and end row ids and another that contains the dataframe where I want to calculate the mean for all rows between those coordinates.

First dataframe:

| id | Exon region start (bp) | Exon region end (bp) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 577 | 647 |
| 1 | 648 | 1601 |
| 2 | 1602 | 1670 |
| 3 | 1671 | 3229 |
| 4 | 3230 | 3304 |

Second Dataframe:

| id | chrom | pos | mean | median | over_1 | over_5 | over_10 | over_15 | over_20 | over_25 | over_30 | over_50 | over_100 | average_exon_coverage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 12141 | 0.029005 | 0 | 0.021939 | 0.000105 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 |
| 1 | 1 | 12142 | 0.029216 | 0 | 0.021622 | 0.000105 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 |

I have managed to create a column in the new dataframe 'average_exon_coverage' and tried to calculate the mean for the start and end positions but I am not sure what I am doing wrong, my code is below:

```
meanList = []
for x in range(exon['Exon region start (bp)'].astype(int), exon['Exon region end (bp)'].astype(int)):
    meanList.append(exomes_avg_mean['mean'])
    exomes_avg_mean['average exon coverage'] = numpy.mean(meanList)
    meanList=[]
```

I want to take the first column as start and the second column as end and keep calculating the mean all coordinates between them and put them in the column I have created.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you provide the expected dataframe?

Comment: so you loop with x as variable, but you never use it in the loop? which column from the second dataframe is supposed to be used to select between start and end? also you have a column id, does it matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider -
 First dataframe having range as dfRange
and 
 second datframe having dfData.

Step1- Find the shape of dfRange. using shape you can get max rows.

step2 - using For loop

```
for rowNumber in range(maxRows):
```

you can get each row of dfRange and their corresponding start and end value.

like for any row -> dfRange[rowNumber][0] gives **Exon region start** and

dfRange[rowNumber][1] gives **Exon region end**

Step 3- Slice tempDf= dfData[start:end+1] 
step 4-  sum up and take mean on whatever axis you want of tempDf. 
step 5 - store that results wherever you want.
Step 6 - loop back for other rows

otherwise instead of shape you can directly go for

```
for index, row in dfRange.iterrows():
```